# "comgooglemaps://" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using the Google API with xamarin ios. I'm trying to use the
Schema of URLs of Google Maps to do a search of a site .. this is my code..

```
            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(new    NSUrl("comgooglemaps://")))
                     {

                         var pizza = "comgooglemaps://" + "?q=Pizza&center=37.759748,-122.427135";
                         var busqPizza = new NSUrl(pizza);
                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(busqPizza);

                     }
                     else {
                         Console.WriteLine("No puede usar comgooglemaos://");
            }
```

error..
 -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "comgooglemaps://" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

Comment: I was thinking of a different OSStatus number, the 10814 is a valid error if your device does not have the app installed when calling `CanOpenUrl`, it will be logged. Run your app on a physical device that does have the google maps app and it should launch correctly using your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution but I do not know if it is the correct form but I work. This is the solution instead of using comgooglemaps:// use http://maps.apple.com?xxxxxx

var pizza = "http://maps.apple.com?q=Pizza&center=20.661922,-103.392030";
                            UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(NSUrl.FromString(pizza));